# R: What's wrong with my use of %in%?

Tags: r

I created a flag called `JF` which I initialize to `FALSE`

```
JF <- F
```

I want to change the value to `TRUE` if the (date) value of  `SomeDate` is in a list of dates that I retrieve from SQL Server. I would use `==` instead of `%in%` but there are a couple of different variables like `SomeDate` and any number of dates in `JF.Date`... and also because I want to master the use of `%in%`.

```
sql  <- "select distinct Date_Values from SomeTable"
JF.Date <- sqlQuery(db, sql)  

if (SomeDate %in% JF.Date) {JF <- T}
```

I checked the `class()` of both objects -- `SomeDate` is character, `JF.Date` is a `data.frame`, and `JF.Date$Date_Values` was originally factor, but I tried changing it to character and it didn't fix this issue. There are unrelated reasons that I'm storing `SomeDate` as character at this point in my code.

This returns no error but it doesn't change the value of `JF` to `TRUE` when it should. What am I doing wrong?

You can reproduce this with any arbitrary date assignment like `<- "1970-01-01"` to objects of the same type/classes.

This

```
for (i in 1:nrow(JF.Date)){
 if (SomeDate == JF.Date[i]) {JF <- T}
}
```

**does** work, but again, I want to know how to use `%in%`.

Comment: If both were atomic vectors and of the same type, you could just do `JF <- SomeDate %in% JF.Date`

Comment: @beginneR That seems totally logical, but I just tried it right now and it didn't work : / ...... WAIT ok now I see the problem/solution. It wasn't quite that but that led me to figure it out!!

Comment: You should convert both variables to a proper date format using `as.Date(... , format =" ...")` and then you could do `JF <- SomeDate %in% JF.Date$Date_Values` (without a repdorducible example, it's hard to help in more detail).

Comment: @beginneR that's a logical approach but it's actually not a `class` issue -- see my solution. The example is reproducible though, you can just make up any arbirtrary date value like JF.Date$Date_Value <- "1970-01-01" and SomeDate <- "1970-01-01"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@beginneR had a suggestion that didn't work, but which led me to the solution:

```
JF <- SomeDate %in% JF.Date
```

That makes total sense, yet didn't change the value of `JF` from `FALSE` to `TRUE`, just like my original attempt.

I realized that's because -- while there's only 1 column in this "dataframe" -- there could be multiple columns and R doesn't know which one to look at. This would be a lot more obvious if there were an appropriate Warning or Error message displayed, but nonetheless this works:

```
JF <- SomeDate %in% JF.Date$Date_Value
```

I can't accept my own answer for 2 days, so if anyone comes up with a more useful/comprehensive answer to this question, then I'll consider selecting your answer as a solution over my own. If I'm going to forgoe those points you've got to make it really good though! ;)